# Turn by Turn GPS Navigation on Android Using Android Studio

Tags: google-maps, android-studio, navigation, gps

I want to use the Tun by Turn voice navigation feature that on google maps app in my android app, I've searched a lot but couldn't find answer, I've used google maps direction API for creating the path from the current location to the user's destination, it's part of the idea of the application to help the user navigate,
What API should I use ? or is it even possible to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Google Maps API v3 does not provide the voice feature at all. And Google Maps API v3 and Google Maps applications are completely different ones. So if you want to implement the voice navigation, you need to prepare it.

Best to read the [terms of service](https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#10-license-restrictions). 10.4 (c) ⅲ might be relevant:

ⅲ. No navigation. You will not use the Service or Content for or in connection with (a) real-time navigation or route guidance; or (b) automatic or autonomous vehicle control.

Fortunately, org.apache.cordova.plugin.tts plugin provides that function for Android.

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    tts.speak("Hello");
});
```

Please refer to the link:
https://github.com/domaemon/org.apache.cordova.plugin.tts

Hope it helps.